# Identification of objects in Flash Builder 4

Tags: flash-builder

I have a very simple question, but I do not know how to do that i can handle in AS script object identifier.

For example, I have a few pictures:

```
<mx:Image x="125" y="262" source="card/1.jpg" width="98" height="165" id="card1"/>
<mx:Image x="247" y="262" source="card/1.jpg" width="98" height="165" id="card2"/>
<mx:Image x="379" y="262" source="card/1.jpg" width="98" height="165" id="card3"/>
```

I need to give them a variety of sources taken from the array:

```
card1.source = "http://***/gallery/7/"+String(arrayOfNumber[0])+".jpg";
card2.source = "http://***/gallery/7/"+String(arrayOfNumber[1])+".jpg";
card3.source = "http://***/gallery/7/"+String(arrayOfNumber[2])+".jpg";
```

But this is the wrong decision and need the cycle:

```
for (var i:uint=0; i<=arrayOfNumber.lenght; i++){
card[i].source = "http://***/gallery/7/"+String(arrayOfNumber[i])+".jpg";
}
```

But that i must use instead of **card[i]**?

Answer (score 0):

If you place all the images inside a container such as Group (flex 4.x) or Box (Flex 3), you could cycle through the children / elements of that container:

```
<fx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
    private var arrayOfNumber:Array = []; // Place your image file names here 

    private function loopThroughImages():void
    {
      var n:int = imageContainer.numElements;
      for (var i:int = 0; i < n; i++)
      {
        Image(imageContainer.getElementAt(i)).source = "http://***/gallery/7/"+arrayOfNumber[i]+".jpg";
      }
    }

  ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:Group id="imageContainer">
   <mx:Image x="125" y="262" width="98" height="165"/>
   <mx:Image x="247" y="262" width="98" height="165"/>
   <mx:Image x="379" y="262" width="98" height="165"/>
<s:Group />
```

[Edit: Wow just realized I'm a year too late.]